# Bootstrap : Progressbar doesn't show correctly

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my page i have a progress-bar, i added `col-xs-12 col-sm-8` classes for it and because of these classes, progress-bar doesn't show correctly and appear empty space at start and end of progress-bar.

This is my code: [`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/436Qz/16/)

This is image of output:

[image]

I want progress-bar will be like this picture:

[image]

How can i fix my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing you CSS to:

```
.person-info {
    margin-top : -40px;
    margin-right:109px;
    padding-left: 0px;//ADD THIS
    padding-right: 0px;//ADD THIS
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/436Qz/17/)